# Weird behaviour between aws-cli and AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have very weird issue; I am querying snapshots in my AWS account through AWS CLI and it returns normally the appropriate snapshots

[image]

And when I query one of these snapshot in the console, it can be found as well.

However, when I try to delete either from console or aws-cli, it tells me this snapshot does not exist.

[image]

Same from CLI

[image]

Note: The failed snapshots are public snapshots.

*Excuses for the ugly images*

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what's happening?

Comment: Yes.. Thanks man. I had already a mess cleaning private AMIs, then found twenty-something thousand public AMIs. Relieved.

Comment: So I think I do not get billed for public snapshots in my account, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete public snapshots, unless you are their original owner.